# using preg_replace after getting content from preg_match with regexp

Tags: regex, arrays, syntax, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I'm getting problems with my coding. I'm trying to take out tags from my preg_match_all. I'm still new and learning.

```
preg_match_all("/\<b>\\$(.*?)\<\/b\>/is", $res[0], $Price );
for($i = 0; $i < count($Price); $i++) {
    $Price = preg_replace("/<.*?>/is","",$Price);   

}
foreach($Price[0] as $kgbPrice) 
{
    $PriceArray[] = "<div class='prices' id='kgbdealsPrice'>".$Price."</div>";
}
```

The array is being outputted somewhere else.

I'm getting content which has

```
<b>content</b>
```

Thank you

Comment: [don't parse html with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Are you trying to actually capture what's inside your <b> tags, or just trying to strip out the tags altogether? If it's the latter, you could use strip_tags(), which lets you specify a list of acceptable tags: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php]

Comment: Yeah, this I posted this before I discovered SIMPLEHTMLDOM. That definitely was a much simpler solution.

Comment: @andrewliu consider marking this question as resolved (green tick)

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure where to mark as solved?

Comment: i have posted an answer with your solution. Just click on the tick under the answer vote count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SIMPLEHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) has been used by andrewliu for solving his problem. It was a much simpler solution.